# SwiftUI - Attempt to present SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController... whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swiftui, alert, hierarchy

While this question has been asked previously, none of the threads deal with the latest SwiftUI and iOS15+.

I am seeing this error in console when navigating to a second level in a custom tab view, where the NavigationView is instantiated outside of the custom tab view.

The full error is:

```
[Presentation] Attempt to present <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController: 0x7f8962874800> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_24NavigationColumnModifier__: 0x7f896080dac0> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_24NavigationColumnModifier__: 0x7f896080dac0>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy
```

The hierarchy is as follows:

- Login Page (NavigationView instantiated here) -> Tap NavigationLink
  from this view
- Custom Tab View is displayed -> Tap any tab and see
  the correct view
- Tap a NavigationLink from within one of these views
  and the alert works perfectly
- Tap a NavigationLink from within that view and the error is shown and no alerts work

I know it's a lot of code, but I have been asked to provide code that will compile, and since this is quite a few different files to make this happen, I stripped everything down to the bare minimum so the issue could be recreated.

Here's the code:

App:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    init() {
        let viewRouter = ViewRouter()
        _viewRouter = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewRouter)
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .environmentObject(viewRouter)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewRouter:

```
import Foundation

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var accessView: DisplayView = .home
}

enum DisplayView {
    case settings
    case home
}
```

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: HomeView()
            ) {
                Text("Go To Tab View")
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
        }
    }
}
```

HomeView:

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        switch viewRouter.accessView {
        case .home:
            UserHome()
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        case .settings:
            UserSettings()
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct HomeNavView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 0) {

            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    Image(systemName: "House")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewRouter.accessView = .home
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                    Image(systemName: "Person")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewRouter.accessView = .settings
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }

        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .zIndex(1)
    }
}
```

UserHome:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserHome: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("User Home View")
        HomeNavView()
    }
}
```

UserSettings:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserSettings: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: SectionView()
        ) {
            Text("Go To Section View")
        }
    }
}
```

SectionView (if you try to display an alert here, it works just fine):

```
import SwiftUI

struct SectionView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: AlertView()
        ) {
            Text("Go To Alert View")
        }
    }
}
```

AlertView (This is where you see the error in console and the alert does not work):

```
import SwiftUI

struct AlertView: View {
    @State private var alertTest: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Alert") {
            alertTest = true
        }
        .alert(
            "Alert",
            isPresented: $alertTest,
            actions: {
            Button("OK", role: .cancel) {
            }
        }, message: {
            Text("The alert is working!")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: Doesn't work fine for me. Just accessing that subview (alertView) with an alert in the code causes the error.

Comment: So, either we use different code or different environments - no magic. I copy-pasted your code and provided test environment. That's it.

Comment: My apologies. You're absolutely correct. The problem wasn't what I thought it was. The issue was that I have an if statement at the bottom of my code that checks to see whether or not the user is online, and throws an alert if they are not. The isPresented value of that statement was bound to a Published var in that ObservedObject and when I changed that to be bound to a local @State var it works just fine. Strange that it's not an issue until you get to this hierarchy level but at least I found it. Thank you for testing and responding.